# Does double check and lock pattern works in c++ (not 11)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

On one hand i have this article, which is written in 2004 : 
http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf

It says that using the word volatile won't help, which maybe was true in 2004.

But on the other hand there is this (Wikipedia):

> Double-checked locking can be implemented in Visual C++ 2005 and above if the pointer to the resource is declared with the C++ keyword volatile. Visual C++ 2005 guarantees that volatile variables will behave as fence instructions, preventing both compiler and CPU arrangement of reads and writes with acquire semantics (for reads) and release semantics (for writes).[9] There is no such guarantee in previous versions of Visual C++. However, marking the pointer to the resource as volatile may harm performance elsewhere, if the pointer declaration is visible elsewhere in code, by forcing the compiler to treat it as a fence elsewhere, even when it is not necessary.

source : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Microsoft_Visual_C.2B.2B

so if i don't use "memory barriers" can i use double check and locking in c++ with volatile keyword ?

Comment: IMO not really, because previously to C++11 the language didn't have guaranteed memory model, meaning that you couldn't even portably talk about such things as multithreaded execution and thread interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Both articles are correct. You can't portably write double-checked locking in C++98. However, Visual C++ provides additional guarantees beyond those required by the C++ standard that ensure volatile will work. This is fairly easy for VC to do, at least when it is targeting x86, because x86 has acquire-release semantics anyway.